# Wordpress PHP wrapping some text, but not others?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a wordpress theme and I'm having an issue with the blog post excerpt not getting wrapped with the paragraph tag in some instances. This is the code I'm using:

```
<p class="articletext">
<?php
        the_content(
            sprintf(
                wp_kses(
                    /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                    __( 'Continue reading<span class="screen-reader-text"> "%s"</span>', 'twentynineteen' ),
                    array(
                        'span' => array(
                            'class' => array(),
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                get_the_title()
            )
        );

        wp_link_pages(
            array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentynineteen' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            )
        );

        ?>
        </p>
```

And this does work, there aren't any errors and it outputs the text, the issue is that the first two blog posts excerpts aren't being wrapped in the paragraph tag with the articletext class, but the last one is - this is what the HTML outputs on the page -

```
<div class="entry-content right-text-block">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="/blog-link-one" rel="bookmark">Blog Title 1</a></h2>
    <p class="articletext">
    </p>
    <p class="p1">Blog one excerpt</p>      
    <p class="datesource">
        <a href="/blog-link-one" class="datesource_link" rel="bookmark">
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-16T15:40:52-04:00">2018/11/16</time><time class="updated" datetime="2018-12-13T16:48:04-04:00">2018/12/13</time>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="entry-content right-text-block">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="/blog-link-two" rel="bookmark">Blog Title 2</a></h2>
    <p class="articletext">
    </p>
    <p class="p1">Blog two excerpt</p>      
    <p class="datesource">
        <a href="/blog-link-two" class="datesource_link" rel="bookmark">
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-16T15:40:52-04:00">2018/11/16</time><time class="updated" datetime="2018-12-13T16:48:04-04:00">2018/12/13</time>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="entry-content right-text-block">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="/blog-link-three" rel="bookmark">Blog Title 3</a></h2>
    <p class="articletext">Blog excerpt 3</p>   
    <p class="datesource">
        <a href="/blog-link-three" class="datesource_link" rel="bookmark">
            <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2018-11-16T15:40:52-04:00">2018/11/16</time><time class="updated" datetime="2018-12-13T16:48:04-04:00">2018/12/13</time>
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

All the blog posts are configured the same, and they're all using that PHP code. I can't figure out why the first two are being wrapped in a paragraph tag after the one they should be. Anyone know what might be happening? I'm fairly novice with PHP / wordpress so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you copied this text out of Sketch? By default sketch adds p1 and s1 classes to paragraph and span tags - You need to remove the wrapper and paste the text in as plain text, easiest error-free way is to type it.

Comment: I'm picking this up from another development company, so possibly, I'll check it out